# non-homogeneous PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose I have a linear PDE of the form 
$u_{y} + u_{x} = x^2$.

Suppose also that the solution is of the form 
$u(x,y) = f_0(x) + \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_{n}(y) \cos nx + \beta_{n}(y) \sin nx$.

The book I am reading suggests that I may write this as,

$f'_0(x) = x^2$,

$\alpha_{n}'(y) \cos nx - n \alpha_{n}(y) \sin nx = 0$,

$\beta_{n}'(y) \sin nx + n \beta_{n}(y) \cos nx = 0$.

Why is this allowed?

Answer (score 1):

If the solution is on the form :
$$u(x,y) = f_0(x) + \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\alpha_{n}(y) \cos nx + \beta_{n}(y) \sin nx\right)$$

$u_x = f'_0(x) + \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(-n\alpha_{n}(y) \sin nx + n\beta_{n}(y) \cos nx\right)$.

$u_y =  \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\alpha'_{n}(y) \cos nx + \beta'_{n}(y) \sin nx\right)$

$$u_{y} + u_{x} = x^2 = f'_0(x) + \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( -n\alpha_{n}(y) \sin nx + n\beta_{n}(y) \cos nx\right) + \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\alpha'_{n}(y) \cos nx + \beta'_{n}(y) \sin nx\right)$$

To be valid for any $x$ and $y$, it implies : 
$$\begin{cases}
\quad f'_0(x) = x^2\\
-n\alpha_{n}(y)+ \beta'_{n}(y)=0\\
n\beta_{n}(y)+\alpha'_{n}(y)=0
\end{cases}$$
from which  $\alpha_n(y)$ and $\beta_n(y)$ can be derived.

I have not enough information about the textbook and context to more comment.

Note :

Another way for solving $\quad u_x+u_y=x^2\quad$ is the method of characteristics.

The general solution is :
$$u(x,y)=\frac13 x^3+F(y-x)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.

This is consistent with the above form where $f_0(x)=\frac13 x^3\quad,\quad f'_0(x)=x^2$.

$F(y-x)$ can be presented on the form of Fourier series as the above sinusoidal functions.